# Fast Modulo for N^2 formula

Tags: c++, formula

I have a problem, when I am trying to resolv this ecuation,

> ( 1*1 + 2*2 + ... + n*n ) % 10234573

My solution in c++,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n, s= 0;
    cin >> n;
    if (n%10234573 == 0)
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n*(n+1)*((2*n+1))/6 % 10234573;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need a solution for numbers bigger that 10^9 + a fast one.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: What problem you are facing? are you getting some error ? what you are expecting and what you achieved ?

Comment: This take too long time... Need a fast one + a correct one for number bigger that 10^9.

Comment: Too long time? this is O(1) solution, you cannot do better!

Comment: Well... my compilator doesn`t think so... Hm.. And for numbers > 10^9?.

Comment: I can´t see what would be different mathematically with >10^9. Your real problem seems to be that you don´t know where to find a Bignum lib. See GMP. (and, if the divisor always is 10234573 , a normal 64bit int should be enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle the bigger number problem, we need to use number `10234573` in more efficient way.

We know that for `mod`, we have:

```
(m*n) mod x = ((m mod x)*(n mod x)) mod x
```

To use the above formula in our calculation:

```
n*(n+1)*((2*n+1))/6 % 10234573
```

we need to get rid of `dividing by 6`.

We know that to divide a number by 6, we need to divide it to 2 and 3.

So we have

```
unsigned long long int mod = 10234573;

unsigned long long int data[3] = {n, n + 1, 2*n + 1};

bool dividedByTwo = false;
bool dividedByThree = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(data[i] % 2 == 0 && !dividedByTwo){
       data[i]/=2;
       dividedByTwo = true; 
    }
    if(data[i] % 3 == 0 && !dividedByThree){
       data[i]/=3;
       dividedByThree = true; 
    }
}
//Finally, applying mod to our formula
cout<< ((((data[0]%mod)*(data[1]%mod))%mod)*(data[2]%mod))%mod;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the distributivity property of the modulo over multiplication, so you don't overflow.

```
(ab) % p = ((a%p) (b%p)) %p
```

For 3 numbers, you get (using the above formula)

```
(abc) % p = ((ab) c) % p = ((((a%p) (b%p)) %p) (c%p)) %p
```

So instead of doing the multiplication of the 3 numbers first, then the modulo, take the modulo of each number then multiply, then take again the modulo at the end.